# How to create a powershell script to move specific files to a different location?

Tags: powershell

So I have been tasked to write a script that will move files from one folder to another folder, which is easy enough.  The problem I am having is the files are for accounts so there will be a file called DEA05292020.pdf and another file called TENSJ05292020 and each file needs to go to a specific folder (EX. the DEA05292020.pdf file needs to be moved to a folder called DEA and the TENSJ05292020 will move to the TENSJ folder.  There are over a hundred different accounts that have their own specific folder.  The files all start off in our Recon folder and need to be moved at the end of each month to their respective accounts folder.  So my question is how could I go about creating a powershell script to make that happen.  I am very new to powershell and have been studying the "Learn Powershell in a Month of Lunches" and have a basic grasp of it.  So what I have so far is very simple where I can copy the file over to the new folder:

copy-item -path "\Sageshare\share\Reconciliation\PDF Recon Center\DEA RECON 05292020" -destination "Sageshare\share\Account Rec. Sheets\Seperate Accounts\DEA"

This works but I need a lot more automation in regards to seperating all the different account names in the PDF Recon Center folder.  How do I make a script that can filter the account name (IE: DEA) and also the month and year from the name of the file (IE: 052020 pulled out of the 05292020 part of the filename)?

Thanks!

Comment: [1] use `Get-ChildItem`  to get the list of files. [2] iterate thru the collection of file info items with `foreach`. [3] parse the `.BaseName` of each file to get the account prefix. the simplest way looks like just removing all the digits. [*grin*] [4] check for the account dir with `Test-Path`. [5] if it aint there, make it with `New-Item`. [6] move the file with `Move-Item`. ///// that seems to cover the idea. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

If @Lee_Dailey wants to write the code and post it here, I'll delete my answer. He solved the problem, I just code monkeyed it.

Please don't test on everything at once, run it in batches so you can monitor its behavior and not mess up your environment. It moves files in ways you may not want, i.e. if there is a folder named a it'll move everything that matches that folder into it. If you want to prevent this you can write the prescanning if there is a folder more "closely matching" that name before it actually creates the folder itself. Pretty sure it does everything you want however in the simplest way to understand. :)

```
$names =    $(gci -af).name |  
            ForEach-Object {
                if (-not ($_.Contains(".git"))){   
                    $_
                }
            }
if ( $null -eq $names ) {
    Write-Host "No files to move!"
    Start-Sleep 5
    Exit
}
$removedNames = $names | 
                ForEach-Object { 
                    $_ = $_.substring(0, $_.IndexOf('.')) # Remove extension
                    $_ -replace '[^a-zA-Z-]','' # Regex removes numbers
                }
$removedNames = $removedNames | 
                Get-Unique # Get unique folder names
$names | 
ForEach-Object {
    $name = $_    
    $removedNames | 
    ForEach-Object { 
        if ($name.Contains($_)) # If it matches a name
        { 
            if (-not (Test-Path ".\$_")) { # If it doesn't see the folder
                New-Item    -Path ".\" `
                            -Name "$_" `
                            -ItemType "directory"
            }
            Move-Item   -Path ".\$name" `
                        -Destination ".\$_" # Move file to folder
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also I don't know why bottom part is red.. I've tested it on my machine and it worked.